# ECMAScript Export class Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to export the `Produto` class below, but the browser throws an `Uncaught SyntaxError`.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

**I followed this [link](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html) for the `export default` notation.**
And I can use it in other classes/controllers.

I already enabled the chrome://flags for experimental scripts.

What I'm doing wrong?

## JS Code:

```
"use strict";
export default class Produto{
    constructor(codigo,nome,imagem,promocao,preco,desconto){
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.imagem = imagem;
        this.promocao = promocao;
        this.preco = preco;
        this.desconto = desconto;
    };
    lista(products){
        var lista = document.getElementById("lista");
        for(var i=0; i < products.length; i++){
            let produto = new Produto(products[i].codigo,products[i].nome,products[i].imagem,products[i].promocao,products[i].preco,products[i].desconto);
            var column, thumbnail, title, image, old_price, price, btn;
            column = document.createElement("div");
            thumbnail = document.createElement("div");
            title = document.createElement("h1");
            image = document.createElement("img");
            old_price = document.createElement("small");
            price = document.createElement("p");
            btn = document.createElement("a");

            column.classList.add("col-xs-12");
            column.classList.add("col-sm-6");
            column.classList.add("col-md-4");
            column.classList.add("col-lg-4");

            thumbnail.classList.add("thumbnail");

            title.classList.add("text-center");

            old_price.classList.add("old-price");

            price.classList.add("price");

            btn.classList.add("btn");
            btn.classList.add("btn-primary");
            btn.innerHTML = "Comprar";

            title.innerHTML = produto.nome;

            image.setAttribute("src",produto.imagem);

            if(produto.promocao == true){
                old_price.innerHTML = "R$ "+ produto.preco;
                price.innerHTML = "R$ "+ (produto.preco - produto.desconto);
            }else{
                old_price.setAttribute("display","none");
                price.innerHTML = "R$ "+ produto.preco;
            }

            thumbnail.appendChild(title);
            thumbnail.appendChild(image);
            thumbnail.appendChild(old_price);
            thumbnail.appendChild(price);
            thumbnail.appendChild(btn);

            column.appendChild(thumbnail);

            lista.appendChild(column);
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I don't think this is yet supported anywhere.

Comment: @epascarello thanks! really good link

Comment: @pvg you are right! thanks!

Comment: np. one simple way to check without getting bogged down in the possibility you've got the something else wrong is to use a very basic expression like `export const foo = Math.sqrt(2);`. If the browser whines, it is likely not yet supported.

Comment: learned smth now! thank you for the tip!